# How can I set the text directly beneath an image?

Tags: html, css

I have created a container by `<div>` and I also pasted the pattern card and the image into the container.  I am trying to put the text (under the name of `class="under-name"`beneath an image but the text is just sticking in the bottom without any effect.

I have been tried for several ways to move up the text but the text is just still locating in the same place.

The first thing I tried by setting with inline with moving the position by left or right. And I also tried to create the other new container with  and it could not affect anything at all.

I want to move text beneath the image.

Please advise me the way to solve it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYjEW.jpg)

```css
.topcon {
  background-color: #f6f5f5;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height:250px;
  border: 15px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 180px auto 150px auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  .pattern-card
    {
      position: relative;
      right: 50px;
      border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
      bottom: 50px;
    }

    .user-name{
      position: relative;
      width:40%;
      left:0;
      top:1000%
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }

    .victor{
      position: relative;
      background-color:#ffffff;
      border:3px solid #ffffff;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 50px;
      margin-right: auto;
      bottom: 110px;
      width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="topcon">
  <img class="pattern-card"src="images/bg-pattern-card.svg" alt="pattern card at the frame.">
  <img class="victor"src="images/image-victor.jpg" alt="image for Victor">

  <figcaption class="user-name">Victor Crest</figcaption>
  26
  London

  80K
  Followers

  803K
  Likes

  1.4K
  Photos
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your 'user-name' class style to this

```
.user-name {
  position: absolute;
  width:40%;
  left:20vh;
  top: 20vh;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It work!  I have a question that why would you put top:1000%?

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
bottom: 60px;
```

In  `.user-name`class, adjusting the pixels until you have the position you are looking for.

Comment: let me try hold on

Comment: And delete ` top:1000%`

Answer (score 0):

It works as below.  The most important is to you vh
This is my first time to use vh.

```css
.user-name {
  position: absolute;
  width:40%;
  left:20vh;
  top: 20vh;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```